# is there a way to create a scrollfunction for specific timestamps in a video?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrollmagic

I have this scroll effect where its playing through the video on scroll. But is there a way to make it so when I scroll it scrolls down to specific time parts, and then stop on each? to create a "slideshow feel". right now I'm using scrollmagic to achieve what I have.

The code for how it works now:

```
   <div className="intro bg-black">
        <h1 className="uppercase text-center text-white text-5xl">We Present Our New App<span className="text-rose-300">.</span></h1>
        <div className="bounce">
        <i className="fa-solid fa-circle-arrow-down scrollDown text-rose-300 text-5xl"></i>
        </div>
        <video className="appVideo" muted={true} preload="auto" src={video}></video>
    </div>
```

```
           const intro = document.querySelector('.intro');
           const introVideo = document.querySelector('.appVideo');


           // Scrollmagic controller
           const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
           
           let scene =  new ScrollMagic.Scene({
       
               duration: 53000, // length of video in ms
               triggerElement: intro,
               triggerHook: 0
           })
           .setPin(intro)
           .addTo(controller);


           // Video Animation
           let accelamount = 0.1;
           let scrollpos = 0;
           let delay = 0;
       
       
           scene.on('update', e =>{
               scrollpos = e.scrollPos / 1000;  
           });
           
           // Makes the video not stop imideatly when you stop scrolling for smoother experience.
           setInterval(() => {
               delay += (scrollpos - delay) * accelamount;
               introVideo.currentTime = delay; 
           }, 33.33);
```